# ng update did get my angular application to 11.0.0-next.6 but I want the stable version 10.x

Tags: angular

For a client of mine I have a project with Angular version 8.x.x . I want to update the version of Angular to 10.x.x. (Because it is stable)

I did ran all steps of the angular update instructions page:
https://update.angular.io/?v=8.2-10.0

When I run in the commandline ng --version I do get:

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 10.1.7
Node: 12.17.0
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 11.0.0-next.6
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, localize, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1001.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1001.7
@angular-devkit/core            10.1.7
@angular-devkit/schematics      10.1.7
@angular/cdk                    10.2.5
@angular/cli                    10.1.7
@schematics/angular             10.1.7
@schematics/update              0.1001.7
rxjs                            6.6.3
typescript                      4.0.3
```

Is this the correct version that I'm using?

Is it stable enough for the application or do I must downgrade the version to stable 10.2.0 instead of at this moment 11.0.0-next.6, and how?

Can I go further developing the application till 11.x stable version is out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update giving more parameter to ng update:

```
ng update @angular/core@10.0.2
```

[ng update to specific Angular version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52970467/ng-update-to-specific-angular-version)

or

update your package.json manually with the given version

I would go for a stable version, the 11 Version could have breaking changes for every release.

Comment: Thanks for the recommended solutions.

What I did is creating a new angular project in a a new folder. This was automatically the stable Angular version that I needed. I added manually the versions to my package.json, 
 runned 'npm install' and that did the trick. I did ran 'ng update' afterwards and I did get a request from the CLI to update @angular/core only. That's it. Thanks again.